# Проблема при создании shapes в after effects

Tags: after-effects

При создании shapes в after effects 2022 у всех них opacity 15% Как изменить это?

Comment: Думается, что это должно помочь - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esugn.jpg

Comment: Спасибо! Это то, что нужно! Вчера поздно вечером сам разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо нажать ЛКМ именно по тексту Fill и тогда открывается окошко с настройками. В нем почему-то Opacity стоял 15% по умолчанию с момента установки программы.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6wh8.png